# Graylog elasticsearch error IndexerClusterCheckerThread

Tags: elasticsearch, graylog

We are seeing the following error on graylog master node only.
`ERROR   [IndexerClusterCheckerThread] - Error while trying to check Elasticsearch disk usage.Details: Error creating ClusterAllocationDiskWatermarkSettings. This should never happen. - {}`
We are running latest graylog version 5.1.2 and ES version 7.10.2. Mongodb is 6.0.6. We are not seeing this happen in dev just production setup.

We have tried redeploying all pods and removing ES security with no luck.  We also have graylog on master node trying to do WhoisIpLookup for old messages about a month old.